# Submit form values are different from values I put into

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I receive the following values in json:

```
Alarm: "1"
Categories: ["P"]
Users: ["Alexander","Moritz"]
```

and load them into a form with:

```
form.load({
    method:"GET",
    url:'GetSimpleProtocol.json'
})
```

The form fields are:

```
{
    type:'checkbox',
    name:'Alarm',
    boxLabel: 'Alarmieren',
    inputValue: '1'
},{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Kategorie',
    name: 'Categories',
    store:['P'],
    multiSelect: true,
},{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    fieldLabel: 'Label',
    name: 'Users'
}
```

When I do direct submission:

```
form.submit({
    url:'SaveSimpleProtocol.json'
})
```

the field values in the submission POST have changed opposed to what was in the first file:

```
Alarm: true
Categories: [{field1:"P"}]
Users: "Alexander,Moritz"
```

Can I tell my components or the form to change these values back into the required format before submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ComboBox submit value was caused by a code problem (the combobox was filled with selection items only AFTER loading the values into the form. If you do it BEFORE, it works like a charm)

The other two, I solved by deriving new components.

ExtJS TextArea that takes and submits an array of lines:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.ArrayTextArea', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
    alias: ['widget.arraytextareafield'],
    valueToRaw:function(value) {
        if(Ext.isArray(value)) return value.join("\n");
        return this.callParent([value]);
    },
    rawToValue:function(value) {
        if(Ext.isString(value)) {
            if(value.length==0) return [];
            return value.split("\n");
        }
        return this.callParent([value]);
    }
});
```

ExtJS Checkbox that returns inputValue/uncheckedValue instead of true/false:

```
Ext.define('TimeFleX.ux.StringCheckbox', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',
    alias: ['widget.stringcheckbox'],
    getValue:function() {
        if(this.checked) return this.inputValue;
        return this.uncheckedValue;
    }
});
```